# how to run the dialog command with proccess

Tags: linux, bash, process, shell-scripting, dialog

Please look on my code – ( bash script )

I want to display both dialogs on the screen on the same time,

one dialog display the:

**tail –f from - /var/log/proccess1.log**  ,

and the second dialog display the:

**tail –f from the file - /var/log/proccess2.log**

but the sad fact is that I can display only one dialog and not both dialogs ( because when I run the first dialog , the second dialog will activate only if the first dialog will killed )

So I create process on the second dialog **( ….. ) &**    , in order to display both dialogs

But …. the second dialog create process number but not create the second dialog GUI , ( seems that when we create dialog with process , the process not send the dialog to standard output )

So how to  run the second dialog with process but send the dialog GUI to screen ? , or other solution in order to display both dialogs on screen

**My code**

```
     #!/bin/bash

     # this dialog will locate the tail box on the top of the screen
     dialog --begin 15 10  --tailbox   /var/log/proccess1.log  13 125 


     # this dialog will locate the tail box down in the screen
     ( dialog --begin 37 10  --tailbox   /var/log/proccess2.log    13 125 ) &
```

Comment: why the downgrade?   -:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can display multiple dialogs with `--and-widget`.

Try something like:

```
dialog --begin 1 1 --tailboxbg FILE1 10 100 --and-widget --begin 20 1 --tailbox FILE2 10 100
```

Answer (score 3):

You need two backgrounded tailboxes and a static component.  Msgbox will do.

```
dialog --begin 1 2 --tailboxbg a 10 70 --and-widget --begin 13 2 \
  --tailboxbg b 10 70 --and-widget --keep-window --msgbox "Exit" 5 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to follow multiple files is to use [multitail](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/).

```
multitail /var/log/proccess1.log /var/log/proccess2.log
```

Among its features:

- filtering
- highlighting
- automatic and manual mark lines

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of the Unix tail command supports multiple -f as shown below.

```
tail -f /var/log/proccess1.log -f /var/log/proccess2.log
```